# Strange error html form

Tags: html, forms

I'm using *this* code for a form in HTML:

```
<div class="login-wrapper">
    <form>
        <div class="popup-header">

            <span class="text-semibold"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Logging in</span>

        </div>
        <div class="well">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. andre@mail.de">
                <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <i class="icon-lock form-control-feedback"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label>reCaptcha</label>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="..."></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions text-right">
                <input type="submit" id="loginbutton" name="loginbutton" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>  
<!-- /login wrapper -->
```

However, when I press the submit button, it does nothing but giving me a very strange url in my browser's address bar:

> http://localhost/?user=&password=&g-recaptcha-response=&loginbutton=Login

Whenever I fill out fields, it kind of puts the content into the URL:

> http://localhost/?user=peter%40griffin.com&password=somepass&g-recaptcha-response=&loginbutton=Login

The intended PHP code which should be run when pressing the button won't even run or load, since this HTML stuff apparently screws things up. I don't know what I have done the wrong way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the PHP that is supposed to run this located?

You are currently submitting the form data via a GET request to the current page because that is how you setup your form. If you would like to send the data somewhere else, set `<form action="somewhere.php">`

Answer (score 0):

In order for the form to submit somewhere else, you need to set the form elements `action` parameter.

```
<form action="some_file.php">
```

Alternatively, you can take the query string and append it directly to the file path to test your script.

```
http://localhost/some_file.php?user=peter%40griffin.com&password=somepass&g-recaptcha-response=&loginbutton=Login
```

Inside of some_file.php, you would then pull out each of the variables like

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The ***very strange url*** is actually the result of a **GET** request.

The parameters are separated by an **&** so you have:

> user=peter%40griffin.com&password=somepass&g-recaptcha-response=

"User" is the attribute **name** of your input and "peter%40griffin.com" is the **value**

First you need to send your form to an action using the attribute **action="save.php"**, for example an pass the parameters using the **method="POST"**, so the user can't see the values in the URL.

```
<form action="save.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is actually not even the intention. I took this snippet and changed it a tad bit (so it's matching my suggestions), I want to process the data within the same file actually. How will I need to do it then?

Comment: Well, it was just the silly me missed the method="post". Thank you very much. Got it!